# PARTSIZE option for SAS SPD datasets

Tags: sas

I've noticed that when I specify the `partsize` option when creating SPD datasets in SAS9.3 Win7 64bit it doesn't seem to work as intended.

I'm using a simple SPDE libname with no additional parameters.  When creating the dataset I specify the option `partsize=5g` but the files created are ~700MB.  The total size of the combined partitions it creates is approximately 20g, so instead of ending up with 4-5 partitions I get 20 to 30.

Anyone else experienced this or have a workaround?

Comment: I'm not an SPDE expert, but it certainly seems to work for me as expected in a limited test in the same environment.  Can you post a simple working example that shows your problem?

Comment: This example works as expected (5GB files).  I do add the split-datapath option but that doesn't seem to be relevant to your problem (I was curious about performance).  

`libname mylib spde 'c:\temp' datapath=('c:\temp' 'd:\temp');


data mylib.test (partsize=5g);
  set sashelp.class;
  do _t = 1 to 2.5e7;
   output;
 end;
run;
`

Comment: Thanks Joe.  I just ran your code then and it produced 4x3.1g files and a 700MB file.  Still not the 5g requested but a lot better than ~700MB.  I'm going to try this in a different environment and see what happens too.

Comment: Interesting - I got exactly the same result on my alternate environment (XP).

Comment: 3.1G instead of 5G?  That's really interesting.  And it didn't make it all the way up to 21.3G either.  Do you have OPTIONS COMPRESS on?

Comment: Yes I do.  Now that you mention it, it just occurred to me that the source dataset is also compressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently OPTION COMPRESS doesn't exactly work with SPDE as you would expect.

This works as you describe:

```
libname mylib spde 'c:\temp' datapath=('c:\temp' 'd:\temp');
options compress=yes;;

data mylib.test (partsize=5g);
  set sashelp.class;
  do _t = 1 to 2.5e7;
   output;
 end;

run;
```

Turning options compress to NO yields the expected results.  Also, in my brief test, OPTIONS COMPRESS didn't save almost any time (even though a 40% reduction in size), suggesting SPDE doesn't work optimally with COMPRESS.